# Couldn't load the schema for the database model

Tags: ssas, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, upn

I've published my power bi report and when I open it online I get this error.

"Couldn't load the model schema associated with this report. Make sure you have a connection to the server, and try again.
Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details."

```
Activity ID: b8fe0d98-5820-44a9-b6e0-ca54a0b9fadb
Request ID: 0e652b23-3f02-d66a-35f3-fc2e0fc13ac2
Correlation ID: 2849503d-a9d5-a7ed-ce0d-353d5ba667fc
Time: Wed Sep 26 2018 16:34:10 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
Version: 13.0.6781.178
Cluster URI: https://wabi-north-europe-redirect.analysis.windows.net
```

Note:I've used live connection with SSAS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Analysis services live connection. My workaround was going to Gateway.  Clicking the gateway connection then users then map user names. I added the users pbi email account to "Replace"(TestUser@email.com) column and then in the "With" column i placed the SQL LOGIN user account(Domain\TestUser).

ISSUE: 
I think the issue for me was the user was using his PBI account which does not have access to the Analysis Services.